# Is there a way to extract polygons from osm which are not yet attributed?

Tags: geometry, polygon, openstreetmap

I am currently using a proprietary version of Nominatim Geocoder to obtain Polygons from OSM. Additionally I am using Overpass API for smaller, more specific queries.

Taking a closer look into OSM-Data I realized that only polygons which are attributed and declared as such are extracted whilst you can clearly see that there are even more polygons available in the OSM-Basemap.

I was wondering is there any way to also extract those, so I can maximize the output of Polygons from OSM?

Thanks in advance!
Best Regards
LK

Comment: Nominatim is a geocoder. It can query for objects that have a name and/or an address. If you want to extract all polygons then simply extract them directly from the database. Alternatively use Overpass API for extraction.

Comment: @scai Thanks for your answer. As I said in my Question I am already using Overpass API to extract Polygons. But I seem to not get everything. 

For Example: If a Building has no referenced Housenumber in OSM and there was no Polygon drawn by a user I can not extract it from there even tho i can see it in the Map itself as a geometry.

Comment: You can extract anything with Overpass API. If you fail to extract a specific element then maybe your query is wrong.

Comment: @scai Yes i can extract anything with Overpass API which has been created by the community. Still i cannot extract the buildings which are not yet created by anyone. I can see those buildings as renderred feature in the OpenStreetMap. It may be that those Building Polygons are only style and dont have content linked to it. But then again im asking myself if I can get the native Data which OSM is using to produce the Map itself.

Comment: If you see these buildings rendered on an OSM map then either: They do exist in OSM (in which case you can also download them via Overpass API). Or they don't exist in OSM and come from an additional data source (in which case you can't download them via Overpass API). Your description is still very vague. Can you show an example?